# Debugging a Gradle 1.12 dependency resolution issue

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, gradlew

I am using Gradle 1.12 to build an Android library.  The build script works fine and the artifacts are installed to both a Maven local repository and deployed (using an S3 wagon Gradle plugin) to a remote Maven repository.  When these artifacts are referenced by a Gradle (1.12) build of a sample app using the Maven local repo, all works fine.  When the remote repository is used, a Gradle dependency resolution error is reported [details on the error will be provided later].

To get more information about the problem in order to fix my script or file a bug report, I would like to do some debugging of Gradle 1.12 while the sample app build script runs.  Eclipse would seem to have the debugger of choice but configuring Eclipse is the subject of this post.

Following advice on the Gradle forums, it is straightforward to configure Gradle startup options to suspend on startup and await a connection from a client debugger (Eclipse).

Configuring Eclipse to do this is proving difficult.  At first glance, it would seem that one needs a Gradle plugin.  Spring Source provides a recommended one.  But this plugin appears to bury and use Gradle 1.10.  Perhaps upgrading this plugin to use 1.12 is easy and an answer that details how to do this would be a great answer.

The critical pieces of the answer I am looking for will enable me to place breakpoints in Gradle classes and step through source code until I either find a bug or figure out what I might be doing incorrectly in my build script.

Alternative approaches, such as using Intellij or Android Studio would be good answers as well if accompanied by details and/or references that make it clear how to enable the Gradle debugging process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging Gradle works exactly the same as (remotely) debugging any other Java application. No Gradle plugin is needed for this. In a nutshell, you need to start a remote debugging session from an Eclipse project that has Gradle sources. One way to create such a project is to clone the Gradle GitHub repository and run `gradlew eclipse`.

Comment: OK, that was helpful and if I understand you correctly this will have the net effect of making the clone an Eclipse project which I can open and then create a debug configuration that will attach to the build script I have kicked off which should be in a suspended state.  Then I let it continue until it stops in breakpoints I have set.  That the gist?

Comment: To add a few more details for those who are, like me, infrequent Eclipse users, one does not need to actually build anything in the Eclipse Gradle project, just add the port to the debug configuration and click on the Debug button after setting a suitable breakpoint.  Finding the correct subproject for linking to the sources does get a bit tricky but is workable.